# JAXB - unmarshalling a XML-File

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I try to unmarshal a xml-file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="map">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="country" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="x" type="xs:integer" />
                        <xs:element name="y" type="xs:integer" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

an example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<map name="usa" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="field.xsd">
<country>
    <name>Test1</name>
    <x>110</x>
    <y>20</y>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Test2</name>
    <x>200</x>
    <y>30</y>
</country>
<country>
    <name>Test3</name>
    <x>350</x>
    <y>80</y>
</country>
</map>
```

and i created the following classes to do so:

```
package game.view.gui;

public class ObjectFactory {

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public Map createMap() {
        return new Map();
    }
}
```

and

```
package game.view.gui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement( name = "map" )
public class Map {
@XmlAttribute
private String name;
private List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

@XmlElement( name = "country" )
public List<Country> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}

public void setCountries( List<Country> countries ) {
    this.countries = countries;
}
}
```

and

```
package game.view.gui;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "country")
public class Country {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int x;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private int y;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

I always get an exception in which it seems like the xml doesn't fit to the created pojos. I tried to do it equally to a tutorial I read. The exception appears in this line of code:

```
 Map map = (Map) unmarsh.unmarshal(file);
```

Can you tell what I need to change in the pojos that everything works?

Edit1:
Exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"map"). Expected elements are (none)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should include the exception in your question.

Comment: Ok did it. Wasn't sure if it's necessary.

Comment: How did you create the `JAXBContext`?

Comment: JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("game.view.gui");

Comment: How you created classes? Manually? If it right try use **xjc** tool from jdk.

Comment: I installed two different xjc tools but when i try to use them i just get the message that com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade could not be found. And when i try to abort the "Generating JAXB Classes from Schema (Cancel)" i need to shut down eclipse and kill the process with the task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectFactory` class you created is missing the required `@XmlRegistry` annotation.  Without this annotation `ObjectFactory` will be treated like a regular domain object.

Comment: Yeah that worked. But now i get an Exception: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "countries" - but I cant find the second countries property - or maybe i just dont understand the exception

Comment: @baxbear - By default JAXB expects the annotations to be on the property (get or set method).  If you annotate the field you should specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the class:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `JAXBContext` (which you use to create the marshaller and unmarshaller instances), you need to pass the root classes of your schema — typically they'll be tagged with `@XmlType` and/or `@XmlRootElement` — so that the context knows which classes it is working with. What it doesn't do is go off and scan all the classes on your classpath on the off-chance that they might have something relevant to say; that'd be very expensive!

Practically, change:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance();
```

to:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Map.class);
```

You might also need to specify the namespace mapping (to the empty namespace) explicitly in your annotations (e.g., via the `namespace` field of the `@XmlRootElement` annotations), and I find that the easiest way to debug JAXB contexts is often to generate the schemas that they encode via their `generateSchema` method (with a dummy output resolver which just causes them to be dumped to `System.out`…)

Comment: I found that I could _exactly_ reproduce the error message given when I used an empty set of bound classes.